Using 2 GPU in forgeui
i have an RTX 4080 Super and a Quadro RTX 6000, but i want to use the 2 gpu in the same process at the same time but no matter how i try and optimize in the code, only using one of the 2 gpus in image generation. I read some forums and there i read that its possible to use the 2 gpus. So basically i just want to utilize my 2 gpu memory and 3D load in the same process.
Here is the code what i tried:
import os
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn.parallel import DataParallel
from modules import launch_utils

args = launch_utils.args
python = launch_utils.python
git = launch_utils.git
index_url = launch_utils.index_url
dir_repos = launch_utils.dir_repos

commit_hash = launch_utils.commit_hash
git_tag = launch_utils.git_tag

run = launch_utils.run
is_installed = launch_utils.is_installed
repo_dir = launch_utils.repo_dir

run_pip = launch_utils.run_pip
check_run_python = launch_utils.check_run_python
git_clone = launch_utils.git_clone
git_pull_recursive = launch_utils.git_pull_recursive
list_extensions = launch_utils.list_extensions
run_extension_installer = launch_utils.run_extension_installer
prepare_environment = launch_utils.prepare_environment
configure_for_tests = launch_utils.configure_for_tests
start = launch_utils.start

def main():
    if args.dump_sysinfo:
        filename = launch_utils.dump_sysinfo()
        print(f"Sysinfo saved as {filename}. Exiting...")
        return

    # Set CUDA devices
    cuda_visible_devices = "0,1"
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = cuda_visible_devices

    # Verify GPU availability
    print(f"Using {torch.cuda.device_count()} GPUs")
    for i in range(torch.cuda.device_count()):
        print(f"Device {i}: {torch.cuda.get_device_name(i)}")

    # Example model (replace with your actual model)
    model = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(10, 10),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(10, 1)
    )

    # Use Data Parallelism to utilize both GPUs
    if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
        model = DataParallel(model, device_ids=[0, 1])

    model.to('cuda')

    # Handle VRAM warnings and environment variables
    vram_state = "NORMAL_VRAM"
    device = "cuda:1"
    total_vram = 16376
    total_ram = 32458
    pytorch_version = "2.3.1+cu121"
    print(f"Launching Web UI with arguments: --device {cuda_visible_devices}")
    print(f"Total VRAM {total_vram} MB, total RAM {total_ram} MB")
    print(f"pytorch version: {pytorch_version}")
    print(f"Set vram state to: {vram_state}")
    print(f"Device: {device} NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4080 SUPER : native")
    print("Hint: your device supports --cuda-malloc for potential speed improvements.")
    print("VAE dtype preferences: [torch.bfloat16, torch.float32] -> torch.bfloat16")
    print("CUDA Using Stream: False")

    # Launch the web UI
    start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

